# Spring AOP on a bean point cut designator and method?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, aop, spring-aop

I'm currently trying to make use of aspect-oriented programming in a Spring project where the pointcut is a wildcard expression on a group of bean names and for a specific method of those beans.

I tried this at first:
`@Before("bean(*Processor)")` but it applies to every method of the processor beans.

I then tried:
`@Before("bean(*Processor) && execution(* execute(..))")` just to see if I could get it to apply to all Processor beans when execute is called.

Any help to make this only apply to certain beans and within them a certain method would be brilliant.

cheers,

AP.

Comment: The expression is valid and should be able to advise execution of `execute` method of all `*Processor` beans . If this is not expected , please provide clarity on what distinguishes the beans ( among the `*Processor`) that should be advised ?

Comment: @krigaex I'm not too sure what happened for this expression not to work, whether it was a classpath issue or not, but it now works. Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then tried:
> `@Before("bean(*Processor) && execution(* execute(..))")`

This works beautifully. If it does not work for you, maybe you have a problem elsewhere. Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Spring components for testing:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70534907;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SomeService {
  public void doSomething() {}
  public void execute() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70534907;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class FirstProcessor {
  public void doSomething() {}
  public void execute() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70534907;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SecondProcessor {
  public void doSomething() {}
  public void execute() {}
}
```

**Example application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70534907;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) {
    appContext.getBean(SomeService.class).doSomething();
    appContext.getBean(SomeService.class).execute();
    appContext.getBean(FirstProcessor.class).doSomething();
    appContext.getBean(FirstProcessor.class).execute();
    appContext.getBean(SecondProcessor.class).doSomething();
    appContext.getBean(SecondProcessor.class).execute();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q70534907;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("bean(*Processor) && execution(* execute(..))")
  public void logBeanMethodsOfInterest(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
(...)
2021-12-31 10:41:39.422  INFO 16032 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q70534907.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 4.013 seconds (JVM running for 6.271)
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q70534907.FirstProcessor.execute())
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q70534907.SecondProcessor.execute())
2021-12-31 10:41:41.069  INFO 16032 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
(...)
```